# What is securable for manage multiple environments xcode ios?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, config, plist

What i refered for manage multiple environment is there is a two option to manage multiple environments. Once is Plist and another one is configuration file.

In plist :

We have set the all API keys and BaseURL value in Build setting with the key(MY_CRASHLYTICS_API_KEY)and set the Fabric key ${MY_CRASHLYTICS_API_KEY} and accessing value via plist in Model class.

In Configuration file :

1)Based on the environment we have created the xcconfig file and variables are assigned as Server URL.

2)set the xcconfig files for configuration.

3)Add the Server URL in info plist and accessing the configuration value  from model.

Ref link : https://thoughtbot.com/blog/let-s-setup-your-ios-environments

**My question is which one is secure? Plist or config**

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"?  Probably the answer is neither. Both methods result in the api keys being available to your app, so both methods can leak the key. Embedding the key directly in your binary requires a little more work on the part of an attacker than simply fetching it from a server, but not much.

Comment: We are handling fabric and firebase API key. So we want securable configurations to handle API keys. Can we use  #if development preprocessor for managing multiple environments?